# TensorBoard: How to plot histogram for gradients?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard

TensorBoard had the function to plot histograms of Tensors at session-time. I want a histogram for the gradients during training.

`tf.gradients(yvars,xvars)` returns a list a gradients.

However, `tf.histogram_summary('name',Tensor)` accepts only Tensors, not lists of Tensors.

For the time being, I made a work-around. I flatten all Tensors to a column vector and concatenate them:

`for l in xrange(listlength):
   col_vec = tf.reshape(grads[l],[-1,1])
   g = tf.concat(0,[g,col_vec])
grad_hist = tf.histogram_summary("name", g)`

What would be a better way to plot the histogram for the gradient?

It seems a common thing to do, so I hope TensorFlow would have a dedicated function for this.

Comment: See the [optimize_loss](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c936c06a20b867eaa868e9f2c4fb53856391b18f/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/optimizers.py#L41) function which is yet to be documented.  Either use that function for optimization or copy its [implementation of gradient histograms](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c936c06a20b867eaa868e9f2c4fb53856391b18f/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/optimizers.py#L114).

Comment: Thanks user728291. This helped me a lot

Answer (score 11):

Another solution (based on [this quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-examples-of-tensorflow-that-shows-how-to-monitor-the-jacobian-and-or-the-hessian#uzPgw)) is to access the gradients directly from the optimizer you are already using.

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(..)
grads = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)
grad_summ_op = tf.summary.merge([tf.summary.histogram("%s-grad" % g[1].name, g[0]) for g in grads])
grad_vals = sess.run(fetches=grad_summ_op, feed_dict = feed_dict)
writer['train'].add_summary(grad_vals)
```

Comment: by `loss` you mean the tensor, the string or the function type? Also do you know how to do the same when using `tensorflow.keras`.

Answer (score 8):

Following the suggestion from [@user728291](https://stackoverflow.com/users/728291/user728291), I was able to view gradients in tensorboard by using the the `optimize_loss` function as follows. 
The function calling syntax for [optimize_loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/optimize_loss) is

```
optimize_loss(
loss,
global_step,
learning_rate,
optimizer,
gradient_noise_scale=None,
gradient_multipliers=None,
clip_gradients=None,
learning_rate_decay_fn=None,
update_ops=None,
variables=None,
name=None,
summaries=None,
colocate_gradients_with_ops=False,
increment_global_step=True
)
```

The function requires `global_step` and is dependent on some other imports as shown next.

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import variable_scope
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes
from tensorflow.python.ops import init_ops
global_step = variable_scope.get_variable(  # this needs to be defined for tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss()
      "global_step", [],
      trainable=False,
      dtype=dtypes.int64,
      initializer=init_ops.constant_initializer(0, dtype=dtypes.int64))
```

Then replace your typical training operation

```
training_operation = optimizer.minimize(loss_operation)
```

with

```
training_operation = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
      loss_operation, global_step, learning_rate=rate, optimizer='Adam',
      summaries=["gradients"])
```

Then have a merge statement for your summaries

```
summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

Then in your tensorflow session at the end of each run/epoch:

```
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir_run_x, sess.graph) 
summary_str = sess.run(summary, feed_dict=feed_dict)
summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, i)
summary_writer.flush()  # evidently this is needed sometimes or scalars will not show up on tensorboard.
```

Where `logdir_run_x` is a different directory for each run. That way when TensorBoard runs, you can look at each run separately. The gradients will be under the histogram tab and will have the label `OptimizeLoss`. It will show all the weights, all the biases, and the `beta` parameter as histograms.

UPDATE: Using tf slim, there is another way that also works and is perhaps cleaner.

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = rate)
training_operation = slim.learning.create_train_op(loss_operation, optimizer,summarize_gradients=True)
```

By setting `summarize_gradients=True`, which is not the default, you will then get gradient summaries for all weights. These will be viewable in Tensorboard under `summarize_grads`